# Cannot store file in storage folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to store file in storage folder

```
 if(!Storage::exists('/public/files')) {
          Storage::makeDirectory('/public/files', 0777, true); //creates directory
        }
 Storage::put('/public/files/test.wav', file_get_contents($blobInput));
```

but directory and files are not getting created, I have tried `php artisan:storage:link`

but same issue. Thanks

Comment: Is your `/public/files` writable by the user PHP is using? Do you get any error - and if so, which?

Comment: @Roboroads: Yes it is writable

Comment: Doies your code actually get to this section? I'd test this with adding a dd() right above it and see if the code stops executing.

Comment: Try: `Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('', $file, $filenewname); `